# Is it possible for me to check and see if a value is entered in for ipv4?

Tags: windows, vbscript

I have a requirement to ensure that a value is entered in a server for ipv4 ip address, subnet mask, default gateway, a value for DNS and a value for WINS.

I don't necessarily need to check against those values to ensure they are correct since the correct values are pulled from a seperate internal website. I don't have any way to interface with it. So I just want to make sure it is completely entered and ipv6 is not being used.

I can't seem to find anything to help me on this. I looked through the registry to see if I could find anything there to grab.

No luck =/

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear.  It almost sounds like you want to read a value from an input field, but then you say something about the registry.  You need to ask more clearly where you are looking for said information.

With that in mind, assuming you mean you want to figure out if the system has acquired an IP address, etc., then consider the following.

1) You can use the Run method and execute `ipconfig /all` and parse its results.

2) You can use netsh.exe and parse results.  For example:

```
C:\> netsh interface ipv6 show address
IPv6 is not installed.
```

There is a lot of information that is able to be gained through this method.

3) You can look in the Registry.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkCards` usually contains a list of numeric sub-keys.  For example, on my system, there is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkCards\9`.  This key contains values:

```
Description REG_SZ "Broadcom NetXtreme 57xx Gigabit Controller"
ServiceName REG_SZ "{A1167D26-ADE0-4CDB-B0C6-1F8C5CF9DF5B}"
```

Of course, that ServiceName GUID will differ.  It is unique to each system, but for the following, I will use it in examples.  You have to replace it by what your system has.

This points to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\{A1167D26-ADE0-4CDB-B0C6-1F8C5CF9DF5B}\Parameters\Tcpip` where the following values are stored:

```
"EnableDHCP"=dword:00000001
"IPAddress"=hex(7):30,00,2e,00,30,00,2e,00,30,00,2e,00,30,00,00,00,00,00
"SubnetMask"=hex(7):30,00,2e,00,30,00,2e,00,30,00,2e,00,30,00,00,00,00,00
"DefaultGateway"=hex(7):00,00
"DhcpIPAddress"="10.152.30.49"
"DhcpSubnetMask"="255.255.255.0"
"DhcpServer"="10.152.28.23"
"Lease"=dword:0003f480
"LeaseObtainedTime"=dword:503f5dd6
"T1"=dword:50415816
"T2"=dword:5042d3c6
"LeaseTerminatesTime"=dword:50435256
"DhcpDefaultGateway"=hex(7):31,00,30,00,2e,00,31,00,35,00,32,00,2e,00,33,00,30,\
  00,2e,00,31,00,00,00,00,00
"DhcpSubnetMaskOpt"=hex(7):32,00,35,00,35,00,2e,00,32,00,35,00,35,00,2e,00,32,\
  00,35,00,35,00,2e,00,30,00,00,00,00,00
```

It also points to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\{A1167D26-ADE0-4CDB-B0C6-1F8C5CF9DF5B}` where the following values are stored:

```
"UseZeroBroadcast"=dword:00000000
"EnableDeadGWDetect"=dword:00000001
"EnableDHCP"=dword:00000001
"IPAddress"=hex(7):30,00,2e,00,30,00,2e,00,30,00,2e,00,30,00,00,00,00,00
"SubnetMask"=hex(7):30,00,2e,00,30,00,2e,00,30,00,2e,00,30,00,00,00,00,00
"DefaultGateway"=hex(7):00,00
"DefaultGatewayMetric"=hex(7):00,00
"NameServer"=""
"Domain"=""
"RegistrationEnabled"=dword:00000001
"RegisterAdapterName"=dword:00000000
"TCPAllowedPorts"=hex(7):30,00,00,00,00,00
"UDPAllowedPorts"=hex(7):30,00,00,00,00,00
"RawIPAllowedProtocols"=hex(7):30,00,00,00,00,00
"NTEContextList"=hex(7):30,00,78,00,30,00,30,00,30,00,30,00,30,00,30,00,30,00,\
  32,00,00,00,00,00
"DhcpClassIdBin"=hex:
"DhcpServer"="10.152.28.23"
"Lease"=dword:0003f480
"LeaseObtainedTime"=dword:503f5dd6
"T1"=dword:50415816
"T2"=dword:5042d3c6
"LeaseTerminatesTime"=dword:50435256
"IPAutoconfigurationAddress"="0.0.0.0"
"IPAutoconfigurationMask"="255.255.0.0"
"IPAutoconfigurationSeed"=dword:00000000
"AddressType"=dword:00000000
"IsServerNapAware"=dword:00000000
"DhcpIPAddress"="10.152.30.49"
"DhcpSubnetMask"="255.255.255.0"
"DhcpRetryTime"=dword:0001fa40
"DhcpRetryStatus"=dword:00000000
"DhcpNameServer"="10.125.28.23 10.125.28.21 192.168.115.2"
"DhcpDefaultGateway"=hex(7):31,00,30,00,2e,00,31,00,35,00,32,00,2e,00,33,00,30,\
  00,2e,00,31,00,00,00,00,00
"DhcpDomain"="my.domain.Local"
"DhcpSubnetMaskOpt"=hex(7):32,00,35,00,35,00,2e,00,32,00,35,00,35,00,2e,00,32,\
  00,35,00,35,00,2e,00,30,00,00,00,00,00
```

This should get you started.  Presumably, you can search the registry for `{A1167D26-ADE0-4CDB-B0C6-1F8C5CF9DF5B}` for other interesting information relating to your network adapter.  For example:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\Dhcp\Parameters\...
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\LanmanServer\Linkage\...
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\lanmanworkstation\Linkage\...
... and so on ...
```

Each of those locations is rich with cross-references and data about the network sub-system.

4) See also [Get active network interface on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/358766/get-active-network-interface-on-windows).  In particular, look at the answer that starts out:

```
You don't need make a new API. Use the WMI class from VBScript.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394216(v=vs.85).aspx
```

5) A link of helpful WMIC commands is here: [WMIC-Snippets > NIC properties](http://quux.wiki.zoho.com/WMIC-Snippets.html#NIC_properties)

Comment: Let me redefine myself. I have a script that is checking a server (multiple servers a day). The script will ensure there is only one network adapter installed and active (that part was easy). I need to verify that there is a manual IP Address/DNS and other info manually entered in to the adapter instead of set to automatic.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use WMI.  You can query remote systems with it, and this can be done in a vbscript context.

Comment: This script is doing many different tasks, this is just one function of many. I'm currently using WMI :). I just need to know what to query. All of the information you posted is very useful and I will be digging down into it -- but I don't know if I'll be able to see if an IP Address is set and added as a manual one?

Comment: Well, for instance, ifconfig /all will list entries with "Teredo" in them if IPV6 is set up.  An address is (probably) manually set if "Dhcp Enabled" is no.  I say probably, because DHCP isn't necessarily the only way for a system to acquire an address from somewhere else.  For multi-homed NICs, there could be more than one set of configuration for the NIC.  You can find the same information different ways.  This article might be helpful if you are concerned about different addresses set up in addition to the standard one:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457118.aspx